# airflow doen't log anywhere

Tags: logging, configuration, airflow

I have installed last version airflow with : 
`sudo pip install apache-airflow`

And added a very basic DAG : 
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py

My issue is that i canot see logs anywhere.
I tried clicking DAG + view log -> i can see : 
Log by attempts and nothing more

And in the default config folder :
/home/user/airflow/logs/scheduler/latest/
is empty

Any idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: Has your DAG successfully run? What do you see on the Airflow UI?

Comment: I can see in the task instance details : 
All dependencies are met but the task instance is not running. In most cases this just means that the task will probably be scheduled soon unless:
The scheduler is down or under heavy load
The following configuration values may be limiting the number of queueable processes: parallelism, dag_concurrency, max_active_dag_runs_per_dag, non_pooled_task_slot_count
- This task instance already ran and had its state changed manually (e.g. cleared in the UI)
If this task instance does not start soon please contact your Airflow administrator for assistance.

Comment: Well you're not seeing any logs because the task instance isn't running.

Comment: yes thats what i guessed seeing that comment.

Comment: Ok just started the scheduler and it worked